# Are <progress> and <meter> elements are form elements?

Tags: html, forms, element, progress

Mozilla listed all html elemetns [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) and `<progess>` & `<meter>` elements grouped as `<form>` elemens there. I wanted to ask if they are `<form>` elements or not? I mean should I use them in the `<form>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mozilla and official W3C spec docs, both [`<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) [<sup>W3C</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-progress-element) and [`<meter>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) [<sup>W3C</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-meter-element) are valid within any parent node that accepts [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

To answer more directly: it's not *required* to have them within a `<form>` element. The question of if you *should* use it is entirely dependent on your design and whether or not it makes sense for you to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Only the `<form>` element is a form element.

The HTML specification lists a number of  [form-associated elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#form-associated-elements). This list does not include `<progress>` or `<meter>`.

The same section does, however, list `<progress>` and `<meter>` as *labelable elements* so they can have a `<label>` associated with them like most form controls.

The [`<progress>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#elementdef-progress) and [`<meter>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#elementdef-meter) may both be used "Where phrasing content is expected", so they can be used inside or outside of forms.